# How can I re-use the model type from a view in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

How can I reuse my declared model type? At the top of the view there is the declaration

```
@model mySpace.viewModels.viewModel
```

What I want to do is later on in the page, do something like

```
@for( viewModel vM in ViewBag.viewModels )
{
 //some foo bar
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a strongly typed view, you really shouldn't be even thinking about ViewBag/ViewData. Once you have strongly typed view to a view model all you have to do in this view is use the properties of this view model, like so:

```
@foreach (viewModel vm in Model.SomeSubModels)
{
    //some foo bar
}
```

or even better, to avoid the horrible `foreach` loops in your views, you could use using editor templates (if you need to edit some properties):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeSubModels)
```

or using a display template (if you only want to display values of your view model properties to the user):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeSubModels)
```

So here's are a couple of basic rules to follow when designing an ASP.NET MVC application (in that order):

1. you forget about ViewBag/ViewData. It's as if they didn't exist. You simply wipe them out of existence. You will do a real service to yourself if you forget about them.
2. you define a view model that is a class containing all the properties that your view will need.
3. you have your controller action query your repositories and domain models and map the results to this view model that will be passed to the view.
4. in the corresponding view you simply use the properties of the view model that the controller action provided to display some information.

Rule number 1. is the real basics and the most important one. If you don't respect this rule, you really aren't doing ASP.NET MVC correctly.

Comment: I have a view which lists items, and also allows for item creation. I did not want to post back the entire list when a user wishes to create an item which is why, in this case, I opted not to use the strongly typed view model because I didn't want to have to repost the entire list just to add one item.

Comment: @TravisJ, there's absolutely no scenario where you should opt-out of using strongly typed view models in ASP.NET MVC and that you should opt-on for ViewBag/ViewCrap. View models are the way to go. They will solve every problem you have. Just don't be afraid of adding new classes to your project.

Comment: If the controller decorated with `[httppost]` accepts the viewmodel, and the viewmodel was passed in to the view with a full list, wont that list also be posted?

Comment: I am mostly concerned with the speed of the post.

Comment: @TravisJ, I have strictly no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify. If I have a ViewModel that is populated with a list of items (to show all), and also has a blank single item (to post back), is there a way to only post back the single item without posting the whole list of items back?

Comment: @TravisJ, it's up to you to decide what you want to *postback*. It's you that's sending this postback, not as in classic WebForms where the entire ViewState was posted back. For example you design a form. In this form you decide what input fields to include. Or you design an AJAX request to call the controller back. Based on your decisions, you can send whatever you want to the server.

Comment: Thank you. As usual, you are correct :). In a test run I posted back the view model, and only the parameters setup in the textboxfor sections were posted. The others were all null.